# javascript being commented out in page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have two WordPress installs - our main site which is installed on root, and a test site which is installed in a directory on root.

They are both multisite installations and both have basically the same plugins and theme.

I have a button that adds a product and leads to a shopping cart. On the test WordPress site, the button works fine. On the main site (on the root of domain), javascript in the button seems to be commented out, disabling the button.

I have tried everything I know to do, including everything in the "Using Javascript" section on the WordPress support site.

No matter what, I can not seem to get the button working. Is there any way I can get WordPress to stop commenting out the Javascript in the button?

Here is a test button on the main WordPress site (button does not work):
http://www.lifeleap.org/shopping2

Here is a test button on the test WordPress site (button does work):
http://www.lifeleap.org/newblogtest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a JavaScript error on your page which is preventing it from working. It looks like the issue is that you have JavaScript embedded in your post content, and the `wpautop` filter is inserting `<br>` tags into it, breaking it - see the `<br/>` at the end of each line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/if(typeof cart=="undefined")
document.write("<scr"+"ipt src="/manage-test/application/cart/views/public/js/cart.js?d98720"></scr"+"ipt>");/*]]>*/</script><br
/> <input
type="button" onclick="cart.addBasketExternal(this,2); return false;" value="Enroll Now"><br
/><
```

It is recommended to host JavaScript in external *.js files.

Comment: I see the issue you have spotted. Any ideas on a workaround to keep this from happening?

Comment: Don't use inline javascript, remove the `wpautop` filter from `the_content` (the be aware this will generally change how your formatting works), use a shortcode that causes your script to not be filtered.

Comment: The correct thing to do would be to include your javascript in the `wp_head` or in an external file - not inline. You can edit `functions.php` to do this (overwritten if you upgrade your theme), write a custom plugin, or drop a file into `wp-content/mu-plugins`.

Comment: I got the break tags removed using this plugin: http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/disable-wpautop/

Comment: The breaks are gone but the issue is still present. If you look at the button which isn't working, you can see the js script in the button is commented out. In the button that is working, the js script is not commented out. Any ideas on what is causing the js to be commented out and any ideas on a fix?

Comment: I could be wrong, but in the source, this seems to be the problem: `/*<![CDATA[*/if(typeof cart=="undefined")
document.write("<scr"+"ipt src="/manage-test/application/cart/views/public/js/cart.js?88a9fa"></scr"+"ipt>");/*]]>*/`

Comment: My only guess is that it is a security plugin/setting on your production server. I would use an external JS file.

Comment: That did it! 
I put this in the head:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myscript.js"></script>`

and included the js in that script. 

You can see the button works fine here:
http://www.lifeleap.org/shopping/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was stumped.